Grid an A4 page with squares without cut lines/squares
Question
What is the optimal grid size for dividing an A4 sheet into identical squares that align perfectly from edge to edge without any partial squares or cut lines?
Situation
Using the code from a discussion almost 9 years ago :

How can I make a perfect page grid that fits my page for measuring purposes in TikZ?

I was able to produce a 1mm grid, but :

Not all the squares are the same size.
Partial squares cut on all edges form a frame of non-uniform thickness around the document.

Criteria

I work on an A4 document and compile in LuaLaTeX.
I want to keep this way of "manually" creating vertical and horizontal lines.
I want to keep the millimetre display for horizontal/vertical lines.
All squares must be the same size (especially those in the corners).

MWE (compilation with LuaLaTeX)
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{extarticle}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}

\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\newcommand{\showgrid}{
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBoxForeground{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
          overlay,
          remember picture,
          inner sep=0pt,
          outer sep=0pt,
          minor line/.style={help lines, draw=gray!25, on background layer},
        ]
        \foreach \step in {0,...,210} {
          \draw [minor line] ($(current page.north west) + (\step mm,0)$) -- ($(current page.south west) + (\step mm,0)$);
          \node [anchor=north] at ($ (current page.north west) + (\step mm,0) $) {\fontsize{1}{1em}\selectfont \step};
        }
        \foreach \step in {0,...,297} {
          \draw [minor line] ($(current page.north west) - (0,\step mm)$) -- ($(current page.north east) - (0,\step mm)$);
          \node [anchor=west] at ($ (current page.north west) - (0,\step mm) $) {\fontsize{1}{1em}\selectfont \step};
        }
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \showgrid
  \null
\end{document}

Generated PDF open on Affinity


do you mean a 1mm gridrather than a0.1mm` one? I don't really understand what your image is supposed to show. is your point that the bottom right corner 'square' is, in fact, a rectangle? are you aware that there is a limit to the degree of precision you can expect with TeX? are you certain that your screen pixels are square?

The line width is just communicated to the backend (PDF). Your PDF viewer renders this. Depending on zoom level, lines might look different. A line that lies on the Page's side will be missing one half that lies outside the paper. I don't understand point 2. What squares are cut on all edges?

@cfr Indeed, it's 1 mm and not 0.1 mm. It's possible that I didn't fully consider this precision limit in the LaTeX context. Is the grid generated from the provided code as precise as possible?

I was just making a general point. I'm not sure I really understand what you're trying to do. e.g. the partial point @Qrrbrbirlbel asked about, but also the 'mm display'. you see to be judging by the pixel readout from your pdf viewer, which won't typically reflect anything interesting about the pdf, as far as I know. if I measure an area that way and then increase the zoom from 100% to 200% and measure again, the result will be roughly twice as many pixels. the shape and density of the pixels depend on your screen, software etc.

My goal is to create a grid that aligns perfectly with the pixel boundaries of the PDF output. I'm aware that screen display can vary, but I'm using an external tool to examine the actual pixels on my screen. This tool reveals that the grid lines along the edges and some random squares within the grid are not uniform in size compared to others. I'm seeking a solution that ensures all grid lines and squares are consistently sized at the pixel level in the final PDF document.
ps. image added to initial post

You might already know this, but note that if you create something in mm and then measure pixels on your screen, you almost always will get some rounding errors (except if 1 mm is exactly 1 px on your screen, but it is difficult to get an exact zoom, so it still is very likely that you run into rounding problems) ... If you use TeX to create a PDF, you never use pixels as unit, but you use units to be printed on paper and if the result is to be presented on your screen, it needs to be transformed so that it fits the pixels of your display (which is done by your PDF viewer).

Please update your MWE code to a compilable working example. You need a \documentclass (add a4paper in the option), the calc and backgrounds (don't forget the "s" at the end) TikZ library, not a calc package, a \begin{document}...\end{document}, a \showgridin the document, and an object, for example a textt` so you don't obtain a blank PDF. And as said by others, it's a rounding problem, LaTeX and PDF works with lengths, not pixels. About the bottom right corner, use a software that can zoom far more than what you show. For example 500000% (Affinity Designer can zoom more).

@quark67 MWE updated with screenshots of the generated PDF opened on Affinity. As you can see, the dimensions of the document are not round, and the lines extend beyond the margin.


Is this close to the grid you are looking for?  In the code, there  is a variable \d that represents the side of the grid's square in mm.  I guess, considering the size of an A4 sheet of paper, that the only interesting values are 1 and 3.  Above is the output for \d=1and below for\d=3`.
To see it, the last horizontal line must be drawn thicker!
I use remember picture, overlay and the absolute position current page.north west.

The code
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \begin{scope}[blue,
    evaluate={%
      integer \M, \N, \d;
      real \h, \w;
      \d = 1;
      \w = 597;
      \h = 845;
      \w = 210;
      \h = 297;
      \N = \h/\d;
      \M = \w/\d;
    }]
    \node at (current page.north west) (NW) {};
    \foreach \i in {0, ..., \M}{%
      \draw ($(NW.center) +(\d*\i mm, 0)$) -- ++(0, -\d*\N mm);
    }
    \foreach \j in {0, ..., \N}{%
      \draw ($(NW.center) +(0, -\d*\j mm)$) -- ++(\d*\M mm, 0);
    }
    \draw[thick] ($(NW.center) +(0, -\h mm)$) -- ++(\d*\M mm, 0);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I've tried your solution, but it doesn't solve the issue: the lines around the document aren't the same thickness (especially the bottom one). The problem may be that LuaLaTeX generates a document slightly larger than 21*29.7cm (see screenshots in the updated post).
